# Firebase deploy displays welcome screen error message, app link is not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm following all the steps to deploy with Firebase for a React app.

- Firebase login
- firebase init (completed all the steps)
- npm run build
- Firebase deploy

The console is showing deploy completed, but when I try to visit my website link, it's showing a Welcome error message. Why don't I see my content?

[image: Showing This Image]

Comment: Please show your `firebase.json` file. And check that the defined `public` directory points to the correct folder. Sometimes something like 'build/your-app/' is needed, not just `build/`.

Answer (score 0):

At first delete build folder and also delete. Firebase.config file. And again start with firebase login, init and Deploy. It will be worked

Comment: Can you explain Clearly Please.